# How to group parent/child records by flag and collapse to a single record for the combo where the flag is true if one or more expanded was true?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

Sorry about the long title it was difficult to describe what I am trying to do.  It is simple to understand as you will see below, but difficult to summarise into a title.

I have a query that returns the following data:

```
| ParentID | ChildID | Flag |
| 100      | 1       | 0    |
| 100      | 1       | 1    |
| 100      | 2       | 0    |
| 100      | 2       | 0    |
| 200      | 1       | 1    |
| 200      | 1       | 1    |
```

The flag column will only have 1 or 0 in it.
I need to filter the results so that there is only a single row for each parent/child combination.
The flag should be 1 if there were one or more records in the full result set above where it was 1 for the parent/child combo, otherwise it should be zero.

So the result if applied to the above would be:

```
| ParentID | ChildID | Flag |
| 100      | 1       | 1    |
| 100      | 2       | 0    |
| 200      | 1       | 1    |
```

I have this working with just the ChildID and Flag columns:

```
DECLARE @InMemoryResultsFirstPass AS TABLE (ChildID Integer, Flag Integer)
DECLARE @InMemoryResultsRecs AS TABLE (ChildID Integer, Flag Integer)

INSERT INTO @InMemoryResultsFirstPass
      SELECT 1 ChildID, 0 Flag
UNION SELECT 1 ChildID, 1 Flag
UNION SELECT 2 ChildID, 0 Flag
UNION SELECT 2 ChildID, 0 Flag
UNION SELECT 1 ChildID, 1 Flag
UNION SELECT 1 ChildID, 1 Flag

select * from @InMemoryResultsFirstPass

INSERT INTO @InMemoryResultsRecs
SELECT DISTINCT 
    result.* 
FROM @InMemoryResultsFirstPass imr
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            *
        FROM @InMemoryResultsFirstPass imrfp
        WHERE imrfp.ChildID = imr.ChildID
        ORDER BY imrfp.Flag DESC
    ) result

select * from @InMemoryResultsRecs
```

But have been unable to work out how to do this once I add it in the ParentID column.  I have tried a few different approaches trying to do a nested query in the CROSS APPLY with GROUP BY on the ParentID but no matter what I try I lose the ParentID = 200 records:

```
DECLARE @InMemoryResultsFirstPass AS TABLE (ParentID Integer, ChildID Integer, Flag Integer)
DECLARE @InMemoryResultsRecs AS TABLE (ParentID Integer, ChildID Integer, Flag Integer)

INSERT INTO @InMemoryResultsFirstPass
      SELECT 100 ParentID, 1 ChildID, 0 Flag
UNION SELECT 100 ParentID, 1 ChildID, 1 Flag
UNION SELECT 100 ParentID, 2 ChildID, 0 Flag
UNION SELECT 100 ParentID, 2 ChildID, 0 Flag
UNION SELECT 200 ParentID, 1 ChildID, 1 Flag
UNION SELECT 200 ParentID, 1 ChildID, 1 Flag

select * from @InMemoryResultsFirstPass

INSERT INTO @InMemoryResultsRecs
SELECT DISTINCT 
    result.* 
FROM @InMemoryResultsFirstPass imr
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            *
        FROM @InMemoryResultsFirstPass imrfp
        WHERE imrfp.ChildID = imr.ChildID
        ORDER BY imrfp.Flag DESC
    ) result

select * from @InMemoryResultsRecs
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: is it just simply `SELECT ParentID, ChildID, MAX(Flag) FROM table GROUP BY ParentID, ChildID` ?

Comment: @Squirrel thanks for the response.  A college showed me the same technique before I saw this.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I just worked it out:

```
SELECT ParentID, ChildID, MAX(Flag) AS Flag
FROM @InMemoryResultsFirstPass
GROUP BY ParentID, ChildID
ORDER BY ParentID, ChildID
```

Hopefully this helps someone else :-)

Comment: Good job!  There are a bunch of different ways to do it, this may be the simplest.